# Can you disable the restore pages pop up on Microsoft Edge-chromium?

Tags: popup, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

Can you disable the restore pages pop up on Microsoft Edge-Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Registry and disable the functionality that automatically restores the pages that didn’t close correctly.

1. Type `regedit` in the Windows Search field and double-click on the Registry Editor.
2. Then navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`
3. Locate the `RestoreOnStartup` entry and double-click on it.
4. Edit its value to 5.

Or you can achieve the same function through Group Policy. For that, press `Win+R`, type `gpedit.msc`, and press the `Enter` button. Then, navigate to the following path `Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/Startup`, find the option `home page and new tab page`, enable it and change options to `Open a new tab`.

For more details, you could also refer to this doc: [Microsoft Edge - Policies - RestoreOnStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#restoreonstartup).

Comment: That's not a solution. The problemn is that we want edge to open a specific set of pages at startup. If for some reason edge restarts it should do what is asked. Not offer something we don't want or asked for